# How to back-reference objects in self-referencing many-to-many relationship?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am building a blog application and one of the features is being able to follow other users. This creates **many-to-many** relationship between the user which I declared like so:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string
    Password string
    Followers []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_followers"`
}
```

When migrating this model, the following join table is created:

```
join table: user_friends
    foreign key: user_id, reference: users.id
    foreign key: follower_id, reference: users.id
```

**My question is, how can I retrieve the followings of a user?**

To get the followers of a user, I can simply do:

```
var followers []User
db.Model(&user).Association("Followers").Find(&followers)
```

But I can't figure out a way to retrieve the followings in a similar manner. I know I can query the join table to get the followings but this means that for each object thats returned from this query, I'd need another query to get the user associated with the `user_id`. This seems super inefficient at scale.

How can I do this effectively and efficiently?

Thank you!